# Comparing Gini coefficient of 2 distributions

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, estimation, gini

I wonder if it is fair is to compare the gini coefficient of two discrete distributions with different number of elements. If not, how can I adjust the coefficients for a fair comparison.

In particular, I'm interested in the case when the sum of values in both distributions are equal. For example, minutes played by players of two teams in a basketball game if they have different number of players (10 players in one team, 12 players in the other team) but for both teams sums plays 48 minutes x 5.

Other example, different partitioning of some surface in different regions, how to compare inequality for different partitioning if they have different number of subareas.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could start by calculating a standard error for the Gini coefs.  [This paper may help](https://web.archive.org/web/20170706090203/http://www.urosario.edu.co/economia/documentos/pdf/dt65.pdf), it uses bootstrapping for comparison on data from Columbia.  Another paper of interest, using monte carlo is [Statistical Inference and Patterns of Inequality in the Global North](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3844463?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

A similar question was asked here:  [Comparing Gini coefficients: Variance estimation etc. needed?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83873/comparing-gini-coefficients-variance-estimation-etc-needed)            (and so far, no answers).